# How to extract LBP features from a hand contour using opencv c++

Tags: c++, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I am currently working on a hand recognition system. I have been able to detect the hand and draw a contour for it. Now, I have to extract features from the hand region. What is the best feature extraction method that i can use?
I was thinking to use Local Binary Pattern, but since i am new to computer vision i don't know how to use it.

Comment: Perhaps a little more detail might help. Since you specify hand recognition does this exclude fingerprints? Is speed an issue? Accuracy?

Comment: It include only the sign the hand makes. I do not know how to proceed with feature extraction of the contour

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you must look at histogram of gradients (HOG), which can be considered as a more general version of LBP. You can have multiple images of hands; by extracting HOG features from each image and using an SVM or neural network classifier, you can learn a statistical model of hand poses. This will help in recognizing an unseen hand. Look also at the current literature on deep learning.

A C++ implementation of HOG is available from vlfeat library [1], which can be called from OpenCV. HOG can be computer from OpenCV also [2].

[1] http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/hog.html

[2] http://goo.gl/8jTetR